# Simular click em Jq ou JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal precisava fazer 4 botões (cima,baixo,direita e esquerda) que chama-se uma função que simulasse o keybord up,down,left e right alguém pode me ajudar.

Simular as teclas pressionadas no teclado.

ou então como fazer uma função usando este js

https://github.com/wwwtyro/Astray/blob/master/keyboard.js

Em resumo quero fazer 4 botões para este jogo que ai clicar faz o mesmo do teclado

http://wwwtyro.github.io/Astray/

Comment: Podes explicar o que entendes por _"simulasse o keyboard"_? queres que dispare eventos que o browser use?

Comment: quero simular como se eu tivesse pressionado no teclado a tecla up

Comment: sim o código eu sei, quero fazer um botão que ao clicar simule a tecla 38 ou keyup usando js ou jq.

Comment: quero simular neste jogo http://wwwtyro.github.io/Astray/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que criar um `evento` do `keydown` e disparar ele no click do botão, fiz um exemplo que retorna um alerta da tecla pressionada, já pegando a partir do evento `keydown`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="up">Pra Cima</button>
<button type="button" id="down">Pra baixo</button>
<button type="button" id="left">Pra esquerda</button>
<button type="button" id="right">Pra direita</button>
<script>

    $('#up').on('click', function(){

        let e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 38;
        e.keyCode = 38;
        $("#up").trigger(e);
    });

    $('#down').on('click', function(){
        
        let e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 40; //key code
        e.keyCode = 40;
        $("#down").trigger(e);
    });

    $('#right').on('click', function(){
        let e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 39; //key code
        e.keyCode = 39;
        $("#right").trigger(e);
    });

    $('#left').on('click', function(){
        let e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 37; //key code
        e.keyCode = 37;
        $("#left").trigger(e);
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        alert(e.keyCode);
    });


</script>
```

Tive que fazer isso para meu jogo e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: estou quebrando a cabeça com isso amigo veja o valor do  e.keyCode = 38 vem indefinido, e quando eu clico em algo no teclado ele dispara tudo de uma vez.

Comment: Testou pelo código aqui no stack? aqui funcionou normal

Comment: Posso afirmar para você que essa é a solução, eu uso e funciona normalmente. agora temos que ver o que você faz dai para frente com as teclas, se quiser poste seu código.

Comment: vou postar perai :D

Comment: Aqui amigo https://bitbucket.org/adilmar/game/src

Comment: Tranquilo, vou dar uma olhada, já dou um feedback

Comment: muito obrigado.

Comment: Realmente tem alguma coisa gerando conflito aqui, vou tentar arrumar para você

Comment: obrigado, pois é rsrsrs menos mal eu não sou tão noob assim kkkk.

Comment: Então, não consegui aqui e não vou ter tempo agora, mas descobri o que é, ele pega um KeyboardEvent então teria que trabalhar com essa API para setar o KeyboardEvent na DOM  e depois disparar o evento. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Comment: Se fosse para implementar em algo que você estivesse criando a resposta simularia as teclas, agora esse game trabalha de forma diferente, desculpa não poder ajudar no momento

Comment: vou tentar aqui muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: sim vou tentar fazer algo do zero :D

Comment: Por nada, se a resposta foi útil pra você e puder votar agradeço ;)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69941/discussion-between-arllondias-and-adilmar).

Answer (score 1):

Esse script, não simula... ele dispara o evento como se a tecla tivesse sido pressionada.

```js
var direcionar = function(keycode){
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = keycode; 
    $(window).trigger(e);   
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <input type="button" value="Acima" onclick="direcionar(38)" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Esquerda" onclick="direcionar(37)"/>    
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Direita" onclick="direcionar(39)"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <input type="button" value="Abaixo" onclick="direcionar(40)"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: estou quebrando a cabeça com isso amigo veja o valor do  e.keyCode = 38 vem indefinido, e quando eu clico em algo no teclado ele dispara tudo de uma vez.

Comment: pera, você quer disparar o evento quando a pessoa clica no botão ou quer que ao teclar as setas os botões sejam pressionados?

Comment: quando clicar no botão veja https://bitbucket.org/adilmar/game/src

Comment: substitua o alert por um console.log(e) que você verá.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, você quer mover um objeto na tela como se estivesse pressionando as setas do teclado. Com este código você simula algo parecido:

```js
var alvo = $('#bola'); // objeto que será movido
var incremento = 2; // números de pixels a se mover
var continua;

$('.btn').mousedown(function(){
   var idx = $('.btn').index(this);
   continua = setInterval(function(){
      moveObj(idx);
   }, 50);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
   clearInterval(continua);
});

function moveObj(idx){

   if (idx == 0 || idx == 2){ // botão UP e DOWN
      var dir = 'top';
      var inc = idx == 0 ? -Math.abs(incremento) : incremento;
      var mover = alvo.offset().top+inc;
   }

   if (idx == 1 || idx == 3){ // botão LEFT e RIGHT
      var dir = 'left';
      var inc = idx == 1 ? -Math.abs(incremento) : incremento;
      var mover = alvo.offset().left+inc;
   }

   alvo.css(dir, (mover+inc)+'px');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; position: fixed; bottom: 20px; left: 20px; z-index: 99;">
   <input type="button" value="&uarr;" class="btn" />
   <br />
   <input type="button" value="&larr;" class="btn" />
   <input type="button" value="&darr;" class="btn" />
   <input type="button" value="&rarr;" class="btn" />
</div>

<div id="bola" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: blue; border-radius: 50%;"></div>
```